# UINavigationBar changes UIBarStyle, even thought the UIBarStyle is different inUIAppearance

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uiappearance

I like to change the `UINavigationBar` of a `TabBarControllers` `NavigationController`, it works fine, but when I change the view by tapping on a tab the `UINavigationBar` changes its style to `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`, but not the `UITabBar`. Before I implemented the themes the NavigationBar style was Black Translucent too, but I removed all the code and changed the colors in the StoryBoard.

I have no idea why my app behaves like this. I have my code in AppDelegate.m, so it should be systemwide.

Thats my code for the white theme:

```
-(void)whiteTheme {

    UIColor *defaultColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(21/255.0) green:(121/255.0) blue:(251/255.0) alpha:1];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:defaultColor];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:defaultColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

}
```

black theme:

```
-(void)blackTheme {

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
}
```

I hope someone knows an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your project at the top, go to your target->general and choose the respective style for your nav bar in the Status Bar Style dropdown box.

another solution: define a specific navigation controller property and use self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar instead of [UINavigationBar appearance]

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```